# How do I save values in a list and also the save content that appears after the search is performed?

Tags: jquery, ajax, list

How do I create a search history based on results after a search is performed and be able to display it in the searchHistory div? Basically display and store all the search values that were entered into the search bar?

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Twitter Search</title>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Twitter Search</h1>

        <div><label for="search">Search twitter: </label>
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search" /></div>

        <div><input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search"></div>
    <div>
        <ul id="resultList">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul id = "searchHistory">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

             $("#btnSearch").click(function () {
                $("#resultList").empty();

                $.ajax({
                    data: {
                        q: $("#search").val(),
                        count: 10
                    },
                    url: 'twitter.php/search/tweets.json?q=my%20search&count=10',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',

                    success: function (serverResponse) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < serverResponse.statuses.length; i++) {
                            var tweet = serverResponse.statuses[i];
                            $("#resultList").append("<li>" + tweet.text + "</li>");
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

        });

    </script>
   </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: you will need some caching arrays and array filter functions as well as conditionals to check arrays before making a call to twitter. Are these things you are familiar with? Not a quick simple thing to throw together , depending on functionality requirements

Comment: All im asking is to create a jquery function that stores the values searched and the responses that come back after the search has atken place inside a div